# read csv file into python dictionary and create html tables

Tags: python, csv

im a beginner in python and im trying to read a csv file into a python dictionary to generate html tables.
i have 30 columns in my file and i want first 4 columns in csv file into my html table as columns and next six columns in another html table and so on..some of my columns includes strings and some includes integers
csv file is like:

```
oposition mat won lost total overs
aa        5   3   2    400   20
bb        4   2   2    300   20
cc        4   3   1    100   19
```

im trying to get the data as :

```
<table>
<tr><td>aa</td> <td>5</td> <td>3</td> <td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>bb</td> <td>4</td> <td>2</td> <td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>cc</td> <td>4</td> <td>3</td> <td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

so far my codes are;

```
infile = open("minew.csv", "r")
mydict = {}
for line in infile:
    words = line.split(",") 
    oposition = words[0]
    mat = words[1]
    won = words[2]
    lost = words[3]
    mydict[oposition] = oposition
    mydict[mat] = int(mat)
    mydict[won] = int(won)
    mydict[lost] = int(lost)

print("<table>")
for o,m,w,l in mydict.keys():
    print("<tr><td>{op}</td> <td>{mt}</td> <td>{wi}</td> <td>{lo}</td>
    </tr>".format(
        op = mydict[oposition],
        mt = mydict[mat]
        wi = mydict[won]
        lo = mydict[lost]))
print("</table>")
```

i cant make my codes working. please anyone help me out. 
much appreciated

Comment: What is it currently outputting?  Please add that to the question.

Comment: ----> 7     mat = words[1]    
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't clear to me that there is only a single character between the columns in your input file, such as a tab ('\t`), in which case I think the csv module might not be applicable. Here's another way of doing it.

```
print ('<table>')
with open('minew.csv') as minew:
    first = True
    for line in minew.readlines():
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            values = line.split()
            print ('<tr>', end='')
            for value in values:
                print ('<td>%s</td>' % value, end='')
            print ('</tr>')
print ('</table>')
```

I think the principal difference between this and your code is that I've used `split()` instead of `split(',')` because there is whitespace between the columns.

This is the output.

```
<table>
<tr><td>aa</td><td>5</td><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>bb</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>cc</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: changed the code and my csv file a bit and this works. im thinking of creating a html page and put this table inside that page. so instead of printing the data i tried to assign the same output into a new variable but my codes are going nowhere so far. is that possible to put the output into a html page editor code list or im thinking of copy and paste the output data into my html page editor. please help me out

Comment: What kind of a variable do you want the output to go into? A string, list of strings? Something else? I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use existing [csv package](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv
with open('minew.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
     for row in reader:
         print('<tr>')
         for fn in reader.fieldnames:
             print('<td>{}</td>'.format(row[fn]))
         print('</tr>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some points you'd better know:

1, you have to skip the header with `next()` when you open the csv file

2, No need to create a new dict to do that, and keep in mind python dict is not ordered.

3, Just use the element in the first loop, as you have already catch them.

4, Close the file after the operation is always a good practice.

Suppose you have csv file:

```
oposition mat won lost total overs
aa        5   3   2    400   20
bb        4   2   2    300   20
cc        4   3   1    100   19
```

Based on your logic, code goes here:

```
infile = open("minew.csv", "r")
next(infile)
print("<table>")
for line in infile:
    words = line.strip().split() 
    oposition = words[0]
    mat = words[1]
    won = words[2]
    lost = words[3]
    print("<tr><td>{op}</td> <td>{mt}</td> <td>{wi}</td> <td>{lo}</td></tr>".format(op = oposition,mt = mat,wi = won,lo = lost))
print("</table>")
infile.close()
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr><td>aa</td> <td>5</td> <td>3</td> <td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>bb</td> <td>4</td> <td>2</td> <td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>cc</td> <td>4</td> <td>3</td> <td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: is your csv file format same as the one in my answer?

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-462acbf24868> in <module>()
      5     words = line.strip().split(",")
      6     oposition = words[0]
----> 7     mat = words[1]
      8     won = words[2]
      9     lost = words[3]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Dush  please check my updated answer, I have noted your csv file delimiter is space, then just change `words = line.strip().split(",")` to `words = line.strip().split()`